# 2 разно оформленных seletc'а на форме, не изменяющие оформление стандартному

Tags: html, javascript, css

Доброго всем времени суток господа

Может ли кто привести пример, 2х разных select'v, что бы оформление их не касалось стандартного select'a, и была заменена стрелка селекта картинкой?

p.s. Поправить все селекты разом - не беда. Найти скрипт, что бы менял охормление - не беда. 2 разных селекта, не изменяющие оформление стандартного - здесь у меня проблемы пошли и с css и с js, хоть и казалось все просто

Comment: Не понимаю в чем может возникнуть проблема :( Назначте разным селекстам разные классы. Стили пишите для классов, а не тэгов. Меняйте классы меняя внешний вид селекта и не трогая стандартный селект без класса. разные классы - разные оформления. Хоть 100500 дизайнов в одну форму...

Comment: да так то оно так, если менять классом только css свойства. Вот если попробовать js заменить стрелку у селектов - все пойдет поедет. Было бы это так просто не спросил бы

Comment: по прежднему в недоумении... что мешает яваскриптом менять стрелку только тем селектам у которых соответствующий класс?

Comment: Уважаемый, я не гуру в JS но тем не менее не смог заменить скриптом оформление у 2х разных select'ов на одной форме, не изменяю оформление у других. Если это что то элементарное, прошу, испугайте кодом. Взять тот же пример от @lampa - удивительным образом легче того, что использовал я, но как ни странно работает применительно к одному селекту (что печально). Был бы это чистый css все было бы просто

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как всегда представлю свой селект, когда-то сделанный в качестве примера для [@heidel](/users/6449/heidel):

[Свой select html javascript css](http://lampacore.ru/2012/11/23/%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-select-html-javascript-css/):

Видим строчку, которая указывает класс:

```
var select_menu = $('<ul />', { class: 'menu' }).insertAfter(select_wrap);
```

Заменяем на:

```
var select_menu = $('<ul />', { class: $this.attr('data_class') }...
```

И у селекта атрибут:

```
<select name='1234' data_class='first_class'>
    <option value='1'>first</option>
    <option value='2'>second</option>
    <option value='3'>third</option>
    <option value='4'>fourth</option>
</select>
```

Вот так можно для каждого селекта установить свой класс.

Comment: Сделал все именно так (Даже попробовал протестировать онлайн на jsbin). Код в том виде по ссылке действительно меняет оформление селекта но у всех, в исправленном виде он просто стандартный.

http://jsbin.com/itojof/1/edit

собственно при всей казалось бы просто те темы с простым селектом разбираюсь с прошлой недели